# Using WebSocket for Web Page Data Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I want to scrape some of the data from [here](https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd) which is implemented based on websockets. So after inspecting the Chrome DevTools for wss address and header:

[image]

and the negotiation message:

[image]

I wrote:

```
from websocket import create_connection

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'Upgrade',
    'Host': 'stream179.forexpros.com',
    'Origin': 'https://www.investing.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'client_max_window_bits',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'ldcvnZNquzPkSNvpSdI09g==',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'Upgrade': 'websocket',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'
}

ws = create_connection('wss://stream179.forexpros.com/echo/894/l27e2ja8/websocket', header=headers)

nego_message = '''["{\"_event\":\"bulk-subscribe\",\"tzID\":8,\"message\":\"pid-1:%%pid-8839:%%pid-166:%%pid-20:%%pid-169:%%pid-170:%%pid-44336:%%pid-27:%%pid-172:%%pid-2:%%pid-3:%%pid-5:%%pid-7:%%pid-9:%%pid-10:%%pid-945629:%%pid-11:%%pid-16:%%pid-68:%%pidTechSumm-1:%%pidTechSumm-2:%%pidTechSumm-3:%%pidTechSumm-5:%%pidTechSumm-7:%%pidTechSumm-9:%%pidTechSumm-10:%%pidExt-1:%%event-393634:%%event-393633:%%event-393636:%%event-393638:%%event-394479:%%event-394518:%%event-394514:%%event-394516:%%event-394515:%%event-394517:%%event-393654:%%event-394467:%%event-393653:%%event-394468:%%event-394545:%%event-394549:%%event-394548:%%event-394547:%%event-394550:%%event-394546:%%event-394551:%%event-394553:%%event-394552:%%event-394743:%%event-394744:%%event-393661:%%event-394469:%%event-394470:%%event-393680:%%event-393682:%%event-393681:%%event-393687:%%event-393694:%%event-393685:%%event-393689:%%event-393688:%%event-393695:%%event-393698:%%event-393704:%%event-393705:%%event-393724:%%event-393723:%%event-393725:%%event-393726:%%event-394591:%%event-393736:%%event-393733:%%event-393734:%%event-393740:%%event-393731:%%event-393732:%%event-393730:%%event-394617:%%event-394616:%%event-393737:%%event-378304:%%event-393645:%%event-394619:%%event-393755:%%event-393757:%%event-393760:%%event-393756:%%event-393758:%%event-393759:%%event-393761:%%event-393762:%%event-394481:%%event-394625:%%event-393754:%%event-394483:%%event-393775:%%event-394621:%%event-394622:%%event-376710:%%event-394623:%%event-394484:%%event-394624:%%isOpenExch-1:%%isOpenExch-2:%%isOpenExch-13:%%isOpenExch-3:%%isOpenExch-4:%%isOpenPair-1:%%isOpenPair-8839:%%isOpenPair-44336:%%cmt-1-5-1:%%domain-1:\"}"]'''

ws.send(nego_message)

while True:
    print(ws.recv())
```

but I'm getting:

```
o

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 647, in <module>
    print(ws.recv())
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 313, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 330, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 343, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 377, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 361, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 309, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 396, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 452, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 115, in recv
    "Connection is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
[Finished in 1.9s]
```

What am I missing here?

**Update 1**: updating code using `WebSocketApp`:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print("message:", message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("error:", error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed.")

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")
    time.sleep(1)
    ws.send(nego_message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    "wss://stream179.forexpros.com/echo/894/l27e2ja8/websocket",
    on_open    = on_open,
    on_message = on_message,
    on_error   = on_error,
    on_close   = on_close, 
    header     = headers 
)

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws.run_forever()
```

but still no success:

```
--- request header ---
GET /echo/894/l27e2ja8/websocket HTTP/1.1

Upgrade: websocket

Connection: Upgrade

Host: stream179.forexpros.com

Origin: http://stream179.forexpros.com

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

Cache-Control: no-cache

Connection: Upgrade

Host: stream179.forexpros.com

Origin: https://www.investing.com

Pragma: no-cache

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: client_max_window_bits

Sec-WebSocket-Key: ldcvnZNquzPkSNvpSdI09g==

Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

Upgrade: websocket

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36




-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: XPKKpUMZLpSYx/1z8Q0499hcobs=
-----------------------
opened
send: b'\x81\xfe\x06{_\xda7\xd2\x04\xf8L\xf0\x00\xbfA\xb71\xae\x15\xe8}\xb8B\xbe4\xf7D\xa7=\xa9T\xa06\xb8R\xf0s\xf8C\xa8\x16\x9e\x15\xe8g\xf6\x15\xbf:\xa9D\xb38\xbf\x15\xe8}\xaa^\xb6r\xeb\r\xf7z\xaa^\xb6r\xe2\x0f\xe1f\xe0\x12\xf7/\xb3S\xffn\xec\x01\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x05\xe2e\xff\x12\xa26\xbe\x1a\xe3i\xe3\r\xf7z\xaa^\xb6r\xeb\x00\xe2e\xff\x12\xa26\xbe\x1a\xe6k\xe9\x04\xe4e\xff\x12\xa26\xbe\x1a\xe0h\xe0\x12\xf7/\xb3S\xffn\xed\x05\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x05\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x04\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x02\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x00\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x0e\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x06\xe2e\xff\x12\xa26\xbe\x1a\xebk\xef\x01\xe0f\xe0\x12\xf7/\xb3S\xffn\xeb\r\xf7z\xaa^\xb6r\xeb\x01\xe8z\xffG\xbb;\xf7\x01\xeae\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe3e\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe0e\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe1e\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe7e\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe5e\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xebe\xff\x12\xa26\xbec\xb7<\xb2d\xa72\xb7\x1a\xe3o\xe0\x12\xf7/\xb3S\x97\'\xae\x1a\xe3e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xe9\x03\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe4l\xe9\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x01\xe1i\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xec\x04\xeae\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6k\xed\x0e\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe7n\xe2\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x02\xe3k\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xef\x06\xe4e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6j\xeb\x02\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe7n\xed\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x01\xe7k\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xee\x01\xe5e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xef\x04\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe6i\xe2\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x02\xe6j\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xef\x03\xebe\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6j\xee\x0f\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe7k\xed\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x02\xe7o\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xef\x03\xe4e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6j\xef\x06\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe7j\xe9\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x02\xe7m\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xed\x03\xe1e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6h\xee\x03\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe4i\xeb\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x03\xe4f\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xee\x00\xe2e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xe2\x07\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe4g\xe8\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x01\xean\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xec\x0f\xe5e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xe3\x03\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe4g\xef\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x01\xeaf\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xec\x0f\xeae\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xe3\x02\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe4f\xe2\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe2k\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x07\xe7e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1h\xe8\x03\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe5m\xe9\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe0j\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x05\xe4e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6j\xe3\x06\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe5l\xec\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe1l\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x04\xe6e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1h\xee\x07\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe5l\xeb\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe1m\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x04\xe2e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6i\xeb\x00\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe4n\xec\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe1h\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xe5g\xe9\x07\xe6e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1i\xee\x02\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe4n\xe3\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe7j\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x02\xe5e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1h\xec\x07\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe5j\xec\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe7g\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebl\xed\x02\xebe\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1h\xec\x06\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x04\xe5i\xe8\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x03\xean\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xec\x05\xe7e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe1h\xef\x03\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xe3\x03\xe6g\xe9\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xe9\x00\xe5j\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xec\x05\xe3e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6i\xe8\x05\xe8z\xffR\xa4:\xb4C\xffl\xed\x01\xe5n\xea\r\xf7z\xbfA\xb71\xae\x1a\xe1f\xee\x01\xe0l\xe0\x12\xf7:\xacR\xbc+\xf7\x04\xebk\xee\x0f\xe6e\xff\x12\xb7)\xbfY\xa6r\xe9\x0e\xe6i\xe8\x03\xe8z\xff^\xa1\x10\xaaR\xbc\x1a\xa2T\xbar\xeb\r\xf7z\xb3D\x9d/\xbfY\x97\'\xb9_\xffm\xe0\x12\xf76\xa9x\xa2:\xb4r\xaa<\xb2\x1a\xe3l\xe0\x12\xf76\xa9x\xa2:\xb4r\xaa<\xb2\x1a\xe1e\xff\x12\xbb,\x95G\xb71\x9fO\xb17\xf7\x03\xe8z\xff^\xa1\x10\xaaR\xbc\x0f\xbb^\xa0r\xeb\r\xf7z\xb3D\x9d/\xbfY\x82>\xb3E\xffg\xe2\x04\xebe\xff\x12\xbb,\x95G\xb71\x8aV\xbb-\xf7\x03\xe6l\xe9\x01\xe8z\xffT\xbf+\xf7\x06\xffj\xf7\x06\xe8z\xffS\xbd2\xbb^\xbcr\xeb\r\xf0"\xf8j'
message: o
send: b'\x88\x82!\xdd\x07\xcf"5'
closed.
[Finished in 2.3s]
```

Comment: I did the same you did. I tried it in c# and plain javascript directly from the browser. In both cases the connection is being closed after the first message is sent to the server. I suspect that the server is closing the connection (maybe some security issue..no idea). If you subscribe to the "onClose" events, you will see that it fires before the second message is sent. Could you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove all the dashes from the message sent and eventually it worked.

```
nego_message = '{"_event":"bulk-subscribe","tzID":8,"message":"pid-0:%%isOpenExch-1:%%pid-8849:%%isOpenExch-1004:%%pid-8833:%%pid-8862:%%pid-8830:%%pid-8836:%%pid-8831:%%pid-8916:%%pid-8832:%%pid-169:%%pid-20:%%isOpenExch-2:%%pid-166:%%pid-172:%%isOpenExch-4:%%pid-27:%%isOpenExch-3:%%pid-167:%%isOpenExch-9:%%pid-178:%%isOpenExch-20:%%pid-6408:%%pid-6369:%%pid-13994:%%pid-6435:%%pid-13063:%%pid-26490:%%pid-243:%%pid-1:%%isOpenExch-1002:%%pid-2:%%pid-3:%%pid-5:%%pid-7:%%pid-9:%%pid-10:%%pid-23705:%%pid-23706:%%pid-23703:%%pid-23698:%%pid-8880:%%isOpenExch-118:%%pid-8895:%%pid-1141794:%%pid-1175152:%%isOpenExch-152:%%pid-1175153:%%pid-14958:%%pid-44336:%%isOpenExch-97:%%pid-8827:%%pid-6497:%%pid-941155:%%pid-104395:%%pid-1013048:%%pid-1055979:%%pid-1177973:%%pid-1142416:%%pidExt-1:%%cmt-1-5-1:%%pid-252:%%pid-1031244:%%isOpenExch-125:"}'
ws.send(nego_message)

while True:
    print(ws.recv())
```

**Outputs:**

```
a["{\"message\":\"pid-3::{\\\"pid\\\":\\\"3\\\",\\\"last_dir\\\":\\\"greenBg\\\",\\\"last_numeric\\\":149.19,\\\"last\\\":\\\"149.19\\\",\\\"bid\\\":\\\"149.18\\\",\\\"ask\\\":\\\"149.19\\\",\\\"high\\\":\\\"149.29\\\",\\\"low\\\":\\\"149.12\\\",\\\"last_close\\\":\\\"149.26\\\",\\\"pc\\\":\\\"-0.07\\\",\\\"pcp\\\":\\\"-0.05%\\\",\\\"pc_col\\\":\\\"redFont\\\",\\\"turnover\\\":\\\"18.13K\\\",\\\"turnover_numeric\\\":\\\"18126\\\",\\\"time\\\":\\\"0:39:09\\\",\\\"timestamp\\\":1666139948}\"}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is calling `ws.recv()` twice. If you simply do:

```py
print(ws.recv())
```

It will not attempt to call `.recv()` on a closed connection. The result of your message output is printing `o` before the stack trace.

As an aside, it seems like you might want a longer running connection  using `websocket.WebSocketApp` ([example](https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/)) for a scrape.

Comment: I changed my code based on your suggestion (post updated) but still no success.